# How to use variable in some select statement with Oracle PL-SQL( or sql-plus)

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, sqlplus

I have a few select statements, they all need to use the same variable. So can I define a variable first, then use it directly in the following statement, like this:

```
declare variable;  -- a to_date function
select statement 1;
select statement 2;
select statement 3;
...
```

So when the conditions change, I can just modify the variables. How can I accomplish it use pl-sql(or sql-plus) in oracle?

Comment: How can you accomplish what? What you described is the correct process. Are you asking how to assign a value to the variable before running the queries? You show how to declare the variable, but not how to assign a value to it - is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express the problem very clearly. My problem is to declare the variable first, then the variable is assigned, and finally used.

Answer (score 1):

You need simple sql*plus variable.

```
variable my_date varchar2(30)

exec :my_date := '01-oct-2019';

select * from t where date_col = to_date(:my_date,'dd-mon-yyyy');

-- other select statements
```

You can achieve this using substitution variable also.

```
select * from t1 where date_col = to_date(&&my_date,'dd-mon-yyyy');

select * from t2 where date_col = to_date(&&my_date,'dd-mon-yyyy');

-- other select statements using &&my_date
```

Here, oracle will prompt for `my_date` once(as we have used two `&`) and its values will be used in all the select statements of that session.

Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, it is ok in sql-plus. When executed in pl-sql, it prompts "ORA-00900" and "ORA-01008" errors. Is there an example in pl-sql?

Comment: Try the second example that is use of two &

Comment: Can you please post the entire code where you are getting error. And also are you using it inside some proc/function?

Comment: I am completely following the example two, but each sql statement prompts the same error "ORA-01008".

Comment: Please add actual code, in which tool you are executing and actual error message in your question

Comment: I am using a third-party tool pl/sql developer.
The actual code is consistent with the example, except that the table name and column name are different.
**sql1:** `select * from t_examp_a a where a.update_time = to_date(&&my_date,'dd-mon-yyyy'); -- ORA-01008: not all variables bound`

**sql2:** `select * from t_examp_b b where b.update_time = to_date(&&my_date,'dd-mon-yyyy'); -- ORA-01008: not all variables bound`